# Cocos 2D iPhone Stopping Particle Emitter

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Is there a way I can tell an emitter to stop spawning particles and then later tell it to start spawning them again ?

I am currently using an emitter as a way of telling the user where their 3D Pointing device is pointed at on the screen. I want it to stop emitting particles when they aren't pointing at the screen.

Comment: are you using the ParticleSystem class ?

Comment: I am using the CCParticleSystemQuad class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `resetSystem` method (kills all particles) or `stopSystem` (stops emitting but all existing particles will live until they die).

I believe `stopSystem` is the method for your purpose as living particles should continue to run but the emitter will not be creating any new particles.

Since it is an open source you can manipulate the `active` property to be used in the `CCParticleSystemQuad`  class logic parts (currently it is `readonly` but you can easily change that fact and update the emitter class logic accordingly)